# Optimal way to use Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

i have a web page that once it loads, it sends a lot of Ajax calls to fill some parts of the page. It's a Django template, it's sending around six calls with code similar to this :

```
$.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/purchase/?name="+me.username, function(data){
        $("#purchase").append(data);
    });
```

sometimes they are called when the user clicks on a button, but they are mostly called when the page is refreshed.

Im new to Ajax, and I want to know if it's the right way to use this technology in an optimal manner. Is it alright to send Ajax calls similar calls that are separate ?

Thanks

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863071/ajax-multiple-calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now i think just put those `$.get()` scripts into a jQuery ready function if you want them to fire when page loads and not on refresh...  And yes its normal for a page to behave like this.  That's what AJAX is meant for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/purchase/?name="+me.username, function(data){
        $("#purchase").append(data);
    });

    //other  $.get 's
});
```

Also use the [jQuery ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation.

Comment: The thing is, they are mixed with the Facebook JavaScript SDK code. Is it better to keep them in one separate file along with the Facebook JS code?

Comment: @MohamedTurki Yes no harm in that. You can keep the js in same file or different files.  It makes no difference until your code is correct.